# int to float conversion in Mongo find

Tags: python, mongodb

As in the code below, I have inserted 4 and 5 in mongo shell. PyMongo gets them as 4.0 and 5.0. I insert 7 from PyMongo. PyMongo gets it as 7.

Why is this happening? I find this shady and I dont want to chase silent production failures in the future. < insert rant here >

**SPOILER WARNING:** I have tried to hide information that may hamper certain students. Please be careful.

From Mongo:

```
$:~/dev/mongouniv$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> use m101
switched to db m101
> db.hw1.findOne()

> db.hw1.insert({"key":4})
> db.hw1.insert({"key":5})
> db.hw1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5566cccaa3e32a78d30eeddc"), "key" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5566ccdda3e32a78d30eeddd"), "key" : 5 }
```

From Python:

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient

# connect to database
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

In [20]: connection.m101.hw1.insert({"key":7})
Out[20]: ObjectId('5566ce513b8aa04a7585120f')

In [21]: list(connection.m101.hw1.find())
Out[21]: 
[
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5566cccaa3e32a78d30eeddc'), u'key': 4.0},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5566ccdda3e32a78d30eeddd'), u'key': 5.0},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5566ce513b8aa04a7585120f'), u'key': 7}]
```

Versions of my Ubuntu packages:

```
dpkg -s python-pymongo
Version: 2.6.3-1build1
dpkg -s mongodb-server
Version: 1:2.4.9-1ubuntu2
dpkg -s mongodb-clients
Version: 1:2.4.9-1ubuntu2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/:

> By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values.

Comment: Yes, your 4 and a 5 are both floats. Try insertin the same numbers with `NumberInt` - you should see the difference

Comment: True. I verified with `db.hw1.find({key : {$type:16}})` for where key is int and `db.hw1.find({key : {$type:1}})` for where key is float.