# PyMongo returns float instead of integer

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection in Mongo in which I store URLs, for that I use the following fields:

- protocol (type: string) - e.g.: https
- host (type: string) - e.g.: google.com
- port (type: integer) - e.g.: 80

In mongo client I execute

```
db.myCollection.find()
```

and it returns

```
{"protocol" : "https", "host" : "google.com", "port" : 80}
```

In Python with PyMongo I execute

```
for service in myCollection.find():
  print service['port']
```

and it returns

```
80.0
```

Is my number stored as integer?

Using PyMongo, how can I return it as integer and not float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint):

> By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point
>   values. The mongo shell provides the NumberInt() constructor to
>   explicitly specify 32-bit integers.

I guess value is stored as float.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30501514/4653485

Answer (score 0):

you can cast it to integer like this:

```
for service in myCollection.find():
  print int(service['port'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Muatik. 
Shouldn't it be already an integer? Seems and odd thing, I store an Integer in the database, it returns as decimal and I need to convert it back to int.

Comment: maybe the type of the value is float when you are inserting? because mongo returns int if it is int, or float it is float. try casting it to integer at the insertion stage and see what happens.